# Can't change ActionBar title text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I've been trying to find solution but none worked for me. 
Activity theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryDesignV4</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleText" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#DE0F17</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

all the attributes in MyActionBar work fine but last one. Title color and sizes are unaffected no matter what.

how can i change it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am using this and it works for me

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

`titleTextColor` is an attribute available for v23 only.

1. Check that in your layout xml file you don't have an `android:theme` attribute specified for your `<Toolbar>`, which would have priority over the main theme
2. Override your `actionBarStyle` attribute as pointed out everywhere over the internets.

> ```
> <style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
>     <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
>     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
> </style>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This line of code works for me

```
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
```

[Image Showing the implementation of a Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH4P9.png)

Answer (score 2):

it's working for me hope it will help u

**Method1:**

```
 Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar)activity.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
 if (toolbar!= null){
 toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);
 }
```

**Method2:**

```
Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar)activity.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
 if (toolbar!= null){
 toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3A1452"));
 }
```

**Method3:**

```
 Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar)activity.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
 if (toolbar!= null){
  toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_carrot));
 }
```